# backuppc exclude syntax (SMB)

Tags: backuppc

I am trying to do a full backup of a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine using backup PC (via SMB).  My server is running Scientific Linux 6.1, with Backup PC 3.2.1.

I have changed the local security policy on the server 2008 machine to allow me to connect via smb, however, every time I do a full backup, I get about 80 errors.  All the errors are similar to:

```
NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \Documents and Settings\*
```

These are all junction points that Windows 7  and 2008 use for backwards compatibility (you can't actually double click to open them).

I have tried excluding a bunch of ways in case my syntax was wrong (via the web gui).. and nothing seems to actually exclude it from scanning those files.  For example:

```
\Documents and Settings\*
\Documents and Settings\
\Documents and Settings
\Documents\ and\ Settings\*
\Documents\ and\ Settings\
\Documents\ and\ Settings
```

I'm running out of ideas.  My other exclusions seem to work.. but I don't want it even looking at these, let alone the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doubling the initial backslash. Also, don't bother trying to escape the spaces with backslashes: that doesn't work. For example, the following setting (entered through the BackupPC web GUI) works for me:

```
\\Documents and Settings
```

Although the "Official" BackupPC documentation is generally very good, it really does fall short in this case. Fortunately, there are "unofficial" docs available through the [BackupPC wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/backuppc/index.php?title=Main_Page) that fill in some of the gaps. In particular, the [Tips and Tricks page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/backuppc/index.php?title=Tips_and_Tricks) contains a lot of good information for admins and end-users.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!  however, I'm still having trouble with some other folders that are not at the root, for example: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED listing \ProgramData\Application Data\*  I can't figure out the syntax to exclude this.. any ideas?

Comment: @Brian: So `\\ProgramData\Application Data` doesn't work? I must admit, I haven't ever needed to exclude subdirectories, so if that doesn't work, I don't have anything else to suggest, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Linux/Unix directory syntax for exclusions - i.e. use slashes instead of backslashes like this:

```
/ProgramData/Application Data
```

Comment: Perhaps it could depend on the version of `smbclient` that BackupPC is using? I don't know. All I know for certain is that I've never had any luck using forward slashes for exclusions on SMB shares. For me, the only successful exclusions have used backslashes.